# VS2013 C99 -- Why Does This Compile?

Tags: c

Can someone tell me why the following code compiles (see getchar below)?  I haven't written C in awhile but I'm pretty sure getchar line shouldn't allow this to compile.  Just installed VS2013 Pro compiled with /Za + /Wall as C.  Looking for C99 compliance.

```
int count_lines(void) {
    char c;
    int num_of_lines = 0;

    while ((c = getchar) != EOF)      // compiles as getchar instead of getchar()
        if (c == '\n') ++num_of_lines;

    return num_of_lines;
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to compiler diagnostics (i.e. error or warning messages), I'm sure you get several for this code

Comment: warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (*)(void)' is all I get........

Comment: That message is telling you that the code is broken and what is wrong with it

Comment: Looking for C99 compliance.... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99 Note: getchar() is actualy a (zero argument) macro (in most implementations)

Comment: If you're asking "why is this a 'warning' instead of an 'error'" then you could ask MS's marketing department ; as far as C99 is concerned there is only "diagnostic message", not different degrees of message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
c = getchar
```

attempts to assign the address of the function `getchar` to the `char` object `c`.

This is a *constraint violation*, meaning that any conforming C compiler must issue a diagnostic. That diagnostic may legally be a non-fatal warning, and a compiler is still allowed to produce a "working" executable -- though its behavior is not defined by the standard.

If a compiler doesn't reject it outright, it will most likely generate a conversion of the function pointer value to type `char`. The standard does not define the behavior of such a conversion (but it's likely to take the low-order 8 bits of the address. This is unlikely to match the value of `EOF`, resulting in an infinite loop.)

As I'm sure you know, the line

```
while ((c = getchar) != EOF)
```

should be

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

As you might not have noticed, the `getchar()` function returns a result of type `int`, not `char`, precisely so that the value `EOF` can be distinguished from any valid character value. You should declare `c` as an `int`, not as a `char`. See question 12.1 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Awesome answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  It's been awhile!

Comment: Note: getchar() can be a macro, and in most implementations it is. (see my comment to the OQ)

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, but if it's a macro it's a function-like macro. Without a `(` as the next token, the name `getchar` refers to the actual function (which, in this context, is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you got a compiler warning for this.  But it compiles because what you are doing is setting `c` to the address of the function `getchar` (of course you are only getting the lowest byte of the address).

Comment: Thank you!  Like I said I'm getting spun back up on C from C#.  I will accept this as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not just assigning to c the value of the address of the getchar function. Which is probably not what you want but not illegal.

```
gcc -g -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘count_lines’:
test.c:7:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by   default]
     while ((c = getchar) != EOF)      // compiles as getchar instead of getchar()
```

Comment: Very few things in C are "illegal". This, however, is a constraint violation.